# How to schedule U-SQL procedure in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I created a stored procedure using U-SQL in Azure data lake.I want to schedule that stored procedure in Azure Data factory.
Is it possible?
I've tried following steps:

1. I created a stored procedure using U-SQL in Azure Data Lake.
2. I've created a script which executes the same procedure.
3. Now, I am trying to run that U-SQL script from ADF.

Is this a right way to execute a U-SQL stored procedure?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you want to schedule the execution of a U-SQL stored procedure/script, you should be able to run the script by using the "DataLakeAnalyticsU-SQL" activity type in ADF.

Comment: You could also use Azure Batch and the USQL PowerShell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-get-started-powershell

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule U-SQL activities in ADF. You can find detailed documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-usql-activity